# How to deploy SqlCe Database into isolatedStorage for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

say, I want to use an existing SqlCe Database which HAS data in it.  I am not sure which is the best way to do it.

1) here is the normal way to create a SqlCe Database for Windows phone

```
using (CountryDataContext context = new CountryDataContext(ConnectionString))    
    {         
        if (!context.DatabaseExists())        
        {            

        // create database if it does not exist            
            context.CreateDatabase();        
        }    
    }
```

But this Database has data in it , so I dont want to create it. I want to deploy it or store in in isolatedStorage.

How should I do it ?? I want to use the data already in the database.

Thanks

Comment: See this blog post: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2012/01/windows-phone-local-database-tip.html

Comment: Amazing stuff. SQLCe is wonderful thing. Will book mark your link. Will do my work and post result later.

Comment: Using V2005, appreciate to show How To install sqlMatel, where to get SqlMetal to generate the Database class? When use SQl command prompt in VS2005, it says something like, Sqlmetal not internal recongized.  Can SQlServer2005 express manage SqlCe Db? Want to enter data there.

Comment: LINQ to SQL / SQLMetal requires .NET 3.5 and VS 2008

Comment: Thanks. Now use VS2008 and VS2008 Command prompt with SqlMetal. Have problem in generating Database Class file. I had posted here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747155/how-to-use-vs2008-command-prompt-to-generate-database-class-from-sqlce-db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include the database file as Content in your application project and it will then be put in your XAP at build time and copied to your application install directory on the phone.

Will you modify this database at all?

If not: you can access the database directly from the install directory and future updates will get any new version of the database automatically (as long as you remember to add them to the XAP).

If you do modify it: then on first install you will need to copy the database to isolated storage before you use it. You will need to watch out if you update the database scheme with a future update.

Comment: Thank you for the tips and notes. I m excited to see SQLCe in Windows phone.

Answer (score 3):

Usually the pattern is to create the database and to configure seed data with it.

Alternatively, if the database is read-only, you can deploy it with your application. See [How to: Deploy a Reference Database with a Windows Phone Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286411%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) on MSDN.

If you want to deploy a database from your development machine for testing purposes, you can use the the [ISETool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) that can take and restore snapshots of an application's isolated storage to/from a local directory:

```
# Copy data from IS to directory
ISETool.exe ts xd <PRODUCT-ID> "C:\TempDirectory\IsolatedStore"

# Copy data to IS from directory
ISETool.exe rs xd <PRODUCT-ID> "C:\TempDirectory\IsolatedStore"
```

Comment: good stuff. Informative info. Let me read all first. Will post result later.