# How to Use VS2008 Command prompt to generate Database Class from sqlCe Db

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce, sqlmetal

created a sqlce Db with VS2008 and save a copy in C:\ Temp08.

can someone point out what was wrong with this Sqlmetal syntax :

sqlmetal c:\Users\DELL\Documents\Temp08\NtwContacts.sdf/ code:c:\Users\DELL\Documents\Temp08\NtwContactsData.cs/language:cs/namespace:LocalDB/context:NtwContactsDataContext /pluralize

Error : SQm1003: 
Input file ' code:c:\Users\DELL\Documents\Temp08\NtwContactsData.cs/language:cs/namespace:LocalDB/context:NtwContactsDataContext  -- does not exist

My machine status :
win7 pro
Using VS2008 and VS2010 express for windows phone.

----- 20/Jul  : have tested these conditions:

sqlmetal c:\Users\DELL\Documents\Temp08\NtwContacts.sdf/code:c:\Users\DELL\Documents\Temp08\NtwContactsData.cs/language:cs/namespace:LocalDB/context:NtwContactsDataContext/pluralize

Try these : no space in between

1)  / code:    ---> /code

2) language:cs   --- > language:csharp  or language:cs

3) C or c

--Result: Same problem

Questions :
1. When I test this : sqlmetal C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Temp08\NtwContacts.sdf

There is a return result on the command prompt with the table structure in Xml .

1. What seem to be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be: NtwContacts.sdf /code

Comment: Thanks. But still have the same problem. Pls refer to the edit i made above.

Comment: Thank you so much. Will get back to you after using it.